# What makes a question active?

Tags: support

Sometimes when I browse the questions list with the "active" filter, some questions appear as if they were recently modified, but in fact they aren't.

Hovering the mouse on the active tab gives this short description

> Questions that have been asked, answered, or updated recently

[This question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/48405/2816) for example is marked as active today , but all the timestamps are from March 7th.
Is this a normal behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yep this is normal.

If you look at the sidebar it says "active  today" as you correctly noted, there is no recreant votes, comments, answers, or edits.

This is one example of where the community bot will "bump" a question so it does not fade away without notice. If you look at the [post history](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/48405/revisions) is says "     Bumped by Community user."

You can read more about [What can cause a question to be bumped?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48578/278094)